# Custom Chassis Jog Control Linux Mint

Tags: hardware-compatibility, volume

I inherented a computer from a friend, it is a custom built PC meant to look like a media center pc. It has a big jog dial on the outside, along with a LCD screen for displaying something (anything I guess). I am looking for some help trying to figure out if I can get the jog dial to work as the volume control. I use Linux Mint 17.3, and I am sure I can get the details of jog dial if I could get a little help in how to probe it. I would love to get the LCD screen to display something as well, but my main focus is on getting the jog dial to control the volume. Anyone have any experience in that area willing to help?